# How to add two NavigationLink in one VStack

Tags: swiftui

I tried to add two NavigationLink in one VStack, but it report a unknown error for me.

```
struct LoginView: View {   
    @State private var selector = ""

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(spacing: 30) { // error `Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate`
                NavigationLink(destination: OneView(), tag: "one",
                               selection: $selector) { EmptyView() }
                
                NavigationLink(destination: TwoView(), tag: "two",
                               selection: $selector) { EmptyView() }
                
                Button("change to view") {
                    self.selector = "one"
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Test Navigation")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selection by signature should be optional, so here is fix

```
struct LoginView: View {
    @State private var selector: String? = ""     // << here

    // ... other your code
```

Comment: Why need add option to it?

Comment: Because such is requirement of `NavigationLink` constructor - `public init<V>(destination: Destination, tag: V, selection: Binding<V?>, @ViewBuilder label: () -> Label) where V : Hashable`